# Access key value pairs in jQuery.each()

Tags: jquery, each

I don't understand the semantics of the jQuery.each function. This peace of code works fine:

```
arr = $("#foo").find("div");

// modify css formatting for all sub-divs
$.each(arr, function(name, value) {
    arr.eq(name).css({backgroundColor:'red', fontWeight:'bold'});
});
```

I don't undernstand why i can't access directly the value like this

```
value.css({backgroundColor:'red', fontWeight:'bold'});
```

because as far as I understand (key,value) pairs, value should be equivalent to arr[name].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `value` will be a raw DOM element, not a jQuery instance. You *could* do this:

```
$(value).css({backgroundColor:'red', fontWeight:'bold'});
```

...but as you're setting the same `css` for all of the elements, you don't want `each` at all:

```
arr = $("#foo").find("div");

// modify css formatting for all sub-divs
arr.css({backgroundColor:'red', fontWeight:'bold'});
```

---

Side note: For those situations where you *do* want to loop through the contents of a jQuery set like `arr` (it's not an array, btw), the more usual thing to use is `arr.each(...)`, not `$.each(arr, ...)`. You can also pass a function into most of the setters like `css`, `text`, `html` and such if you need to set a different value on each element in the set: You return the value for the element out of the function.

For instance, let's say you were going to loop through a set and set the background to `red` if an element was empty, or to `green` if it wasn't:

```
$("selector for the elements").css("background-color", function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "" ? "red" : "green";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the `value` is a dom element reference not a jQuery object so it doesn't have jQuery methods like `.css()`.

There is no need to use a iteration as you have done, you can just call the `.css()` method on the `arr` object which is a jQuery object containing references to all child `div` elements

```
arr = $("#foo").find("div");
arr.css({backgroundColor:'red', fontWeight:'bold'});
```

Comment: Indeed i don't have to use an iteration, but I want to understand how to access such an object.